# How to use rbenv to install Ruby 2.5.1

Tags: ruby, installation, rbenv

I am trying to install Ruby and rbenv but I keep running into errors. I tried researching solutions here and attempted several but did not have success.

Whenever I attempt to download I get:

```
Downloading ruby-2.5.1.tar.bz2...

-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.5/ruby-2.5.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.5.1...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.4 using ruby-build 20200401)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/7s/2q_70_3x7qj4q2gx60mp2lw00000gn/T/ruby-build.20200409195302.36573.PF8HnQ
Results logged to /var/folders/7s/2q_70_3x7qj4q2gx60mp2lw00000gn/T/ruby-build.20200409195302.36573.log

Last 10 log lines:
The Ruby yaml extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/shanellevalencia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1
  --with-openssl-dir=/Users/shanellevalencia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/openssl
  --enable-shared
  --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/opt/readline
  CC=clang`enter code here
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/shanellevalencia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib 
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/shanellevalencia/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/include 
Shanelles-MacBook-Pro:~ shanellevalencia$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please put in the effort to format your question. Formatting helps everyone, from those trying to put together an answer for you, to those following along who want a solution to the same question you're asking. Remember, SO isn't here just to help you, it's to help others in the future, so content, grammar and formatting do matter.

Comment: Why are you installing Ruby 2.5.1? Ruby 2.7.1 is current. What "solutions" did you try? See "[ask]" and the linked pages.

Comment: This question is not really programming related. This may be what you are looking for: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1124

Answer (score 0):

you should be installing latest stable ruby version 2.7 in your machine instead of old versions.

This is a great tutorial for installing ruby using rbenv: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-18-04/#installing-ruby-using-rbenv

I hope it helps. Let me know if you get stuck anywhere and need any help, I will be glad to support you in any way I can.

Comment: Not always an option for developers